# Solidity - Calling parent payable not possible?

Tags: inheritance, parent, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to inherit and override a parent's payable function (and adding some modifier and logic) but so far seem unable to do so.

My first intuitive try was something like this:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return super.test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

and received compile error:

```
TypeError: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function () - did you forget the "payable" modifier?
super.test.value(msg.value)();
```

Give the function a different name doesn't work either so it's not an overriding issue.

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function anotherTest() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return super.test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

I got slightly further by tricking compiler with a casting but this is obviously no good as would cause infinite loop at runtime:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return foo(address(this)).test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

What works is combining the two, i.e. giving it a different name and casting:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function anotherTest() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return foo(address(this)).test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

Now calling bar.test() with 6 wei returns 6 and calling bar.anotherTest() returns 3. But this isn't exactly what I want as it still exposes test() through bar.

So what am I doing wrong, or is this by design? Would really like to understand why Solidity behave this way and if there's a workaround to achieve what I want. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your last example and mark `test` as `internal` in the parent contract. Contracts that inherit from it will still be able to call it, but it will not be executable from an outside call.

```
contract foo {
    function test() internal payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function anotherTest() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return foo(address(this)).test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Raghav. But I believe `payable` cannot be `internal` and by casting `bar` as `foo` I'd be trying to invoke `test` on `foo` directly, or from an outside as you put it.

Comment: Ah, right. Another option is that you could use a modifier to make foo.test() accessible only by bar.

Answer (score 0):

In all your examples you are trying to send ether in what is an internal call with itself that is not how ethereum works and there is no reason to ever do that. Doing so means you probably are confused with a fundamental part of solidity. If you are sending ether to a contract you only need the outermost function to be payable, internal and functions that are overridden do not need to be payable. A way to do what I think you are trying to do is this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract foo {
    function test(uint value) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return super.test(msg.value/2);
    }
}
```